# Can't root because can't turn off verification

Tags: twrp, supersu

How can I turn off verification in TWRP - I see many descriptions that say turn it off in settings, but there's no way to do that that I can see. If I boot into "recovery" mode the touch screen does not work and the up-down buttons do not provide a "settings" option. Also, I have installed the "Official TWRP App" as a regular application, but it also does not have any settings like that. I suppose it's possible that I need to be rooted to have those settings, but that's what I'm trying to do - install SuperSU -- which fails because the install fails the verification test. Any advice?

Comment: What phone are you talking about?  From the TWRP Official app's description:  The Official TWRP App does not require root to perform version checking, however, additional features are available such as image flashing if you grant root permissions.

Comment: If touch doesn't work when you are in recovery then something is wrong with recovery (you probably use ported one). What device you have?

Comment: The phone is a Samsung Galaxy On5.

Comment: My experience is that there are (at least) two versions of TWRP, one is the "Official TWRP App" that runs like a normal app; touch works on that one but a setting to change verification is not on offer. The other is what appears when I enter recovery mode using the various buttons. That one does not use touch at all. So niether one offers the ability to change a "verification" setting.